# Distance between arrows and nodes in tikzcd

Tags: diagrams, nodes, tikz-styles

How can I adjust the default distance between arrows and nodes in [tikz-cd](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd)? I prefer a global solution, but a local solution would also be fine.

I think the default distance is a little bit too large (especially when compared to `xypic`):

```
$\xymatrix{ A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\ C \ar[r] & D }$

$\begin{tikzcd} A \ar{r} \ar{d} & B \ar{d} \\ C \ar{r} & D \end{tikzcd}$
```

Notice that the option

```
shorten >=-2pt
```

only decrements the distance between the arrow tip and the node next to it. I've also tried to use `inner sep`, but this doesn't work for some reason.

Edit: Here is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a [full example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of how you use `shorten >`? Have you tried adding `shorten <` as well?

Comment: Yeah, shorten < is the solution, so easy! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to change the distance between arrows and nodes, you can change the `inner sep` like

```
\tikzcdset{diagrams={nodes={inner sep=2pt}}}
```

or change arrows like

```
\tikzcdset{diagrams={arrows={shorten >=-0.5ex,shorten <=-0.5ex}}}
```

so that they apply to every diagram.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{diagrams={arrows={shorten >=-0.5ex,shorten <=-0.5ex}}}
\begin{document}
  $\xymatrix{ A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\ C \ar[r] & D }$

$\begin{tikzcd} A \ar{r} \ar{d} & B \ar{d} \\ C \ar{r} & D \end{tikzcd}$

$\begin{tikzcd}[nodes={inner sep=2pt}]  %% add here to make it local
   A \ar{r} \ar{d} & B \ar{d} \\ C \ar{r} & D
 \end{tikzcd}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The keys `column sep` and `row sep` can also be set in the optional argument to a specific `tikzcd` environment.

Comment: @egreg True, but that will be local whereas the OP wants it to be global. I have added a note, thanks :) And Good night ;)

Comment: row/column sep determine the distance between the nodes. I would like to change the distance between an arrow and its source/target nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your edit, this answers my question. Both solutions are nice and in fact produce different results. I will have to think which one is best for my file (which contains many monstrous diagrams).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg You are welcome.